# how to share ItemSelectionModel between two ListViews

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

In qml file, there are two ListViews, the left ListView displays all data from QAbstractListModel with checkbox, the right ListView displays all selections from left ListView。how to use ItemSelectionModel to share selections between two ListViews? There is no sample code in QT user manual about how to use ItemSelectionModel .